# Not able to pass arrays to a json string

Tags: json, swift

I have an API to submit some data and I want to pass into this API a json string. This is a format of the json structure that will be passed..

```
{
  "schedule": {
    "departmentId": 18123,
    "taskTypeId": null,
    "dueDate": "2020-01-16T00:00:00.000Z",
    "smatorIds": [
      15102,
      16715
    ],
    "smateeIds": [
      217093
    ]
  },
  "shiftId": null,
  "feedbackEmails": [
    "test.name@ext.myCompany.com"
  ],
  "comment": "test",
  "observations": [
    {
      "typeId": 1,
      "smateeId": 234234,
      "categoryId": 843
    },
    {
      "typeId": 2,
      "smateeId": 43423,
      "categoryId": 123
    }
  ]
}
```

I know that if it was just a string value associated with each key, then I could pass values like so..

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = [

“taskTypeId” : 1,
“Comment”: myCommentView.text!
]
```

But in the json structure given above(the first one), I have arrays within arrays and so on.. 
I’m just not able to figure out how I will pass values so that I can finally make an array structure like the given format..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking how you can create a JSON like structure in Swift array of dictionaries. You just need to replace you `{ }` to `[ ]`. Its that easy!

```
let emailArray : [String] = ["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com","email3@gmail.com"]

let observationArray : [Dictionary<String,Any>] = [
    [
        "typeId": 1,
        "smateeId": 234234,
        "categoryId": 843
    ],
    [
        "typeId": 2,
        "smateeId": 43423,
        "categoryId": 123
    ],
    [
        "typeId": 3,
        "smateeId": 98798,
        "categoryId": 483
    ]
]

let parameters: [String: Any?] = [
    "schedule": [
        "departmentId": 18123,
        "taskTypeId": nil,
        "dueDate": "2020-01-16T00:00:00.000Z",
        "smatorIds": [
            15102,
            16715
        ],
        "smateeIds": [
            217093
        ]
    ],
    "shiftId": nil,
    "feedbackEmails": emailArray,
    "comment": "test",
    "observations": observationArray
]
```

**UPDATE:** To apeend data to observationsArray, you can do it like this:

```
let myExampleObservationData1 : [String:Any] = [
    "typeId": 1,
    "smateeId": 234234,
    "categoryId": 843
]
let myExampleObservationData2 : [String:Any] = [
    "typeId": 2,
    "smateeId": 232143,
    "categoryId": 432
]

var observationArray : [Dictionary<String,Any>] = []

observationArray.append(myExampleObservationData1)
observationArray.append(myExampleObservationData2)
```

`Dictionary<String,Any>` and `[String:Any]` are same thing.

Comment: But @iOSArchitect.com, what I'm concerned is how will I add values to arrays in the above json dynamically. For eg., the number of emails in `feedbackEmails ` can be multiple..and I just want to pass an array to the `feedbackEmails ` key & not individual email id's in case there are multiple emails. Same is the case with `observations`, `smatorIds ` also.

Comment: @kfodof i have updated the answer. Is this what you are looking for? you need to get your emails stored in an array first. Same for observationArray. Then you can pass those in parameters

Comment: That is just what I was looking for @iOSArchitect.com. So if I want to add values to `emailArray ` I can do it like so..`emailArray.append(emailTextfield.text!)`. But if I want to add values to `observationArray ` how could I do that..?

Comment: @kfodof did it help? Please accept the answer if yes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @iOSArchitect.com.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your `Dictionary` into `Data` and the get `String` instance from it like so,

```
let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dict)
let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

**Edit:**

As per your comment this is how you can pass any `array` in your `parameters` json,

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
"taskTypeId" : 1,
"Comment": myCommentView.text!,
"smatorIds": [15102, 6715] //here....
]
```

You can do the same thing for other arrays and dictionaries as well.

Comment: But @PGDev, I first wanted to pass values to arrays if there are more than one value and it was that array that I wanted to pass to the json. I'm not able to figure out how to do that..

Comment: @kfodof Updated the answer as per your requirement.